# Checking site for meta refresh redirects

Tags: redirects, web-crawlers, screaming-frog, meta-refresh

How do you check or crawl site (couple of urls) to explore existing meta refresh redirects?

Screaming Frog doesn't handle them - it indicates a page with meta refresh as 200 (it is partly true), even if `meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0`

Comment: Actually those tools are based on HTTP response, and meta refresh is client side solution which is handle by browser. I don't think you will find some tool which do bunch of operation to check meta refresh tag. Better to do it manually or hire someone to do the job.

Comment: @Goyllo Screaming Frog (and other spiders/crawlers) also parse the HTML response and will often report on meta information found in the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinary HTML page that contains a meta refresh element will indeed return a 200 OK HTTP status (this is *totally* correct). How that HTML response, with a meta refresh tag, is processed by the user-agent/bot is another matter.

However, Screaming Frog SEO Spider does report on pages that contain a meta refresh HTML element - the pages are scanned for several meta elements. In the "Internal" tab, there is a column for "Meta Refresh 1" which can be sorted.

[image: Screaming From - Meta Refresh column]